# delete n largest files in a directory in ubuntu terminal

Tags: bash, ubuntu-14.04

I want to delete n (say 2 in our case) largest files in a directory.

```
files=$(ls -S | head -2)
rm $files
```

This doesn't work because the file names have space and all sorts of special characters in them. I got similar results with this `ls -xS | head -2 | xargs rm`. I guess one should escape all the special characters in the file name but there are various types of special characters. Although it's doable, I didn't expect it to be this complicated. 
I used -Q option to quote the file names, but I still get the same error.

```
Downloads > files=$(ls -SQ | head -1)
Downloads > echo $files
"[ www.UsaBit.com ] - Little Children 2006 720p BRRip x264-PLAYNOW.mp4"
Downloads > rm $files
rm: cannot remove ‘"[’: No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ‘www.UsaBit.com’: No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ‘]’: No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ‘-’: No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ‘Little’: No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ‘Children’: No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ‘2006’: No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ‘720p’: No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ‘BRRip’: No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ‘x264-PLAYNOW.mp4"’: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Do they have quotes in them?

Comment: I thought you meant do I have quotes in the file name. :)

Comment: That **is** what I meant.

Comment: Anyways, glad you got your problem fixed. :D (My solution was going to look a lot uglier than @choroba's... ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[choroba's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38938027/45375) works well, and even though use of `eval` happens to be safe in *this* case, it's better to form a habit of avoiding it if there are alternatives.
The same goes for parsing the output of `ls`.

The **general recommendations** are:

- **Avoid use of `eval`** on input you don't control, because it can result in execution of arbitrary commands.
- **[Do not parse `ls` output](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)**; if possible, use [pathname expansion (globbing)](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/globs).

That said, **sometimes `ls` offers so much convenience that it's hard *not* to use it**, as is the case here: `ls -S` conveniently sorts by file size (in descending order); hand-crafting the same logic would be nontrivial.

**The price you pay for parsing `ls` output is that filenames with *embedded* newlines (`\n`) won't be handled correctly** (as is true of choroba's answer as well). That said, such filenames are **rarely a real-world concern**.

While **`xargs`** applies word-splitting to its input lines by default - which is why handling of filenames with embedded whitespace fails - it ***can*** be made to recognize each input line as a distinct, as-is argument (note that `ls`, when not outputting to a *terminal*, outputs each filename on its *own* line by default):

***GNU* `xargs`** (as used on most Linux distros):

```
ls -S | head -2 | xargs -d $'\n' rm       # $'\n' requires bash, ksh, or zsh
```

`-d $'\n` tells `xargs` to treat each input line *as a whole* as a separate argument when passing arguments to `rm`.

***BSD/macOS* `xargs`** (also works with GNU `xargs`):

This `xargs` implementation doesn't support the `-d` option, but it supports `-0` to split the input into arguments by NULs (`0x0` bytes). Therefore, an intermediate `tr` command is needed to translate `\n` to NULs:

```
ls -S | head -2 | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 rm
```

Comment: This is the perfect solution!

Answer (score 3):

If your `ls` supports the `-Q` option, it will quote all the names in double quotes (and backslash double quotes).

You can't use such an output directly as the argument of `rm`, as word-splitting won't respect the quotes. You can use `eval` to force a new word splitting:

```
eval rm $(ls -Q | head -2)
```

Use this with care! `eval` is dangerous, it can run turn data into running code that you can't control. My tests show `ls -Q` turns newline into `\n` which isn't interpreted as a newline in double quotes!

Comment: Isn't that slightly dangerous?!

Comment: @JefréN.: It seems to replace newline with `\n`, so it is.

Comment: @JefréN. I was thinking the same thing.

Comment: Glad you added the warning ... ! :D